# Normaliser is not the whole group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

I'm aware that the representative of the only conjugacy class of elementary abelian $2$-subgroup of maximal rank $2$ of $G = PGL(3,\mathbb{C})$ in a maximal torus of $G$ is $E$ = {1, $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & I_2 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
I_2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1& 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0& 0& 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ }.

Also it can be computed that $N_{G}(E) = T_{2}. S_3$ where $T_2$ is a two-dim torus. I just can't see why the normaliser is not the whole $G$ because I think $E$ has included all the involution conjugates in $G$ so any $g\in G$ can conjugate $E$ to $E$. Am I missing something here? If I could get some direction or hint, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Why not try conjugating one of the involutions in $E$ with an arbitrary element of ${\rm GL}(3,{\mathbb C})$?

Comment: For context, see also the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505219/representatives-of-conjugacy-classes-of-involutions).